# How hide navigate panel in vaadin sub window?

Tags: components, vaadin

How can i hide top panel with the buttons in vaadin sub windows ?
I need to hide the navigation bar on the subwindow, what bar whene displayed where close button.

```
Window window = new Window();
    VerticalLayout vertical = (VerticalLayout) window.getContent();
    vertical.setMargin(true);
    vertical.setSpacing(true);
    vertical.setSizeFull();
    window.addComponent(componetn);
    window.setWidth(width);
    window.setHeight(heigth);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setModal(false);
    window.setBorder(0);
    getMainWindow().addWindow( window);
```

Comment: i try to hide navigate panel in window.

Comment: i need to hide navigation buttons panel in sub windows

Comment: I didnt get your question can you pls describe a bit more?

Comment: done... please, read now

Comment: do you want to hide close button? or hide window header?

Comment: Have you tried component.setVisible(false)?